# Why does the definition of addition require proofs?

Tags: real-analysis, peano-axioms

The book is *Foundations of Analysis* by E. Landau.

I delve into analysis for the first time. Before I would encounter merely a definition of something in a textbook, but now there is something more. In *Theorem 4* the author gives a definition of addition. Then he first proves that A) for any fixed $x$ there is *at most one* possibility to define $x + y$. Then he proves that B) for each $x$ it *is possible* to define $x + y$.

My question is why does he prove B) that it is possible to define $x + y$? He has already made a definition, so he brought it into existence.

Why does he need proofs here at all? It is a definition, you can define it however you want.

[image]

Comment: A quick note. You can't just define it however you want, it has to be consistent.

Comment: How does the author define addition?

Comment: @DanChristensen: This Theorem 4 is the definition of addition in disguise.

Comment: @Graduate I get it, now. I'm curious... Does Landau start his proof by selecting the same subset of $N^3$ that I do? Or does he make use of some recursion theorem?

Comment: I found an excerpt that contains at least the beginning of the "proof". It doesn't seem do either of these things. I can't make any sense of it. http://fmi.unibuc.ro/ro/pdf/2008/catedre/analiza/miculescu_r/Landau.pdf

Comment: A full quotation of the proof at http://www.lib.uni-bonn.de/PhiMSAMP/Data/Book/PhiMSAMP-bk_Borovik.pdf (p. 4-5) It still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DanChristensen: It was written 60 years ago, maybe that's why it is a bit strange. But it must be correct. Tom Apostol recommended Landau's book in his *Calculus*.

Comment: @DanChristensen I was in the middle of writing a very detailed response to your other question (about Landau's definition of addition) but the question was deleted and I was in the middle of composing it.  Do you still have questions about it?

Comment: @mweiss Sorry. I have now undeleted. I mistakenly thought there was no interest in the question. Yes, I am still interested in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have to simply define addition and hope we get it right.  We can actually prove the existence a uniquely defined add function on $N$ with all the required properties.

We can formally construct the $add$ function on the set of natural numbers $N$ by selecting the following subset of $N^3$:

$\forall a,b,c:[(a,b,c)\in add \iff (a,b,c)\in N^3 $

$\land \forall d\subset N^3:[\forall e\in N:(e,0,e)\in d\land \forall e,f,g:[(e,f,g)\in d \implies (e,S(f),S(g))\in d]$

$\implies (a,b,c)\in d]]$

where $S$ is the successor function on $N$ given by Peano's Axioms.

Using Peano's Axioms, we can prove that the set of ordered triples $add$, so defined, is a function such that, using the prefix functional notation, we have:

$\forall a,b\in N: add(a,b)\in N$

$\forall a\in N:add(a,0)=a$

$\forall a,b\in N:add(a,S(b))=S(add(a,b))$

We can also prove that the $add$ function, so defined, is unique. If $add'$ is another function such that we also have:

$\forall a,b\in N: add'(a,b)\in N$

$\forall a\in N:add'(a,0)=a$

$\forall a,b\in N:add'(a,S(b))=S(add'(a,b))$

then we can prove by induction that $\forall a,b\in N: add(a,b)=add'(a,b)$

We then feel justified referring to *the* add function + (using the infix notation) where

$\forall a,b\in N: a+b\in N$

$\forall a\in N:a+0=a$

$\forall a,b\in N:a+S(b)=S(a+b)$

Answer (score 2):

The proof is necessary to ensure that the definition is actually meaningful.

Suppose, for instance, that I define a binary operation $\circledast$ on $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ as follows:  For any rational numbers $q_1$ and $q_2$, I say that $q_1 \circledast q_2$ is the smallest rational number greater than $q_1 \cdot q_2$.  Great!  Only problem is, no such smallest rational number exists.

Second example:  I define a ternary operation $F$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ as follows:  $F(a,b,c)$ is the solution to the equation $a x^2 + bx + c = 0$.  Terrific!  Only problem here is, sometimes no such solution exists, and sometimes *more than one* solution exists.

Whenever you define something, it's essential to prove that the thing being defined both *exists* and *is unique*.  Otherwise the definition is meaningless.

Comment: Your last paragraph. The author didn't explain it in the first place.